# Python: Rate Limit Multiple Executions of Script

Tags: python, rate-limiting

I am trying to find a way to rate limit individual threads.  Calling the same script multiple times, queuing or throttling subsequent executions to within defined parameters.

I found a lot of multiprocessing and multithreading solutions, but these apply to a single execution of a script.  I am not sure how to handle this for separate executions of the **same** script.

My goal is the limit the number of thread executions to twenty (20) per seconds.  Wait or queue subsequent executions, and continuing to process based on FIFO.

For the sake of testing, let's set the constraints to three (3) per minute.  Not sure where to start, just showing `rate_limit()` as a placeholder.

```
import time

rate = 60
limit = 3

ts = time.time()

def single_task():
    print ts

rate_limit(single_task())
```

Results from multiple executions should look like this:

```
session_1$ ./script.py 
1527483557.76

session_2$ ./script.py 
1527483558.26

session_3$ ./script.py 
1527483559.03

session_4$ ./script.py
hang on a minute... 
1527483560.57 

session_5$ ./script.py 
hang on a minute... 
1527483561.92
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and wrote a little python package ([mp_throttle](https://pypi.org/project/mp-throttle/)) to throttle and monitor multiple threads or processes. You can install it via `pip install mp_throttle`. You can instatiate it with a rate limit and handle the throttle object over to your threads. Then use `.await_fuel()` to block your threads according to limit.

```py
import mp_throttle
import threading
import time

def single_task(throttle):
    while not throttle.kill_flag.is_set():
        throttle.await_fuel()
        print("{}: executed at: {}".format(threading.currentThread().name, time.time()))
    return

throttle = mp_throttle.Throttle(3,60)

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=single_task, args=(throttle,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

throttle.start()
time.sleep(40)
throttle.stop()
```

This would output something like:

```
Thread-1: executed at: 1534428994.0086124
Thread-2: executed at: 1534429014.013284
Thread-3: executed at: 1534429034.0338206
```

Depending on the kind of tasks (regular versus unregular execution time), your system (minimal sleep time and sleeping accuracy) and the rate (higher rates less accurate), some settings and a calibration might be necessary. Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.elpunkt.eu/mp_throttle/index.html) for more on that.